# Android Throttle Button Click

Tags: android, button, throttling

I understand that in some cases, button clicks might need to be throttled (or disabled entirely).  We have been using RxView to handle this case:

```
RxView.clicks(button)
        .throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribe(aVoid -> {
            //do work
        });
```

The case I am unsure about, is when the button click is starting a new activity.  Is it necessary to throttle in this case?  I was initially thinking that as soon as the new activity was started, the old activity would no longer receive any calls to onClick, but now I'm not sure.

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
});
```

Is there an edge case I am missing?  Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you should still throttle that click. When `finish()` is called on an activity, there can still be several milliseconds of time during which you can interact with it.

- When you do `startActivity()` or `finish()`, you are simply queuing this request. The actual actions happen a bit later on, **asynchronously**.
- As a result, when you start a new activity, and finish the current one, these two things happen asynchronously, and totally independent of each other. It actually doesn't even matter if you finish the current activity first and start the new activity in the next line of your code.
- Before starting up completely, B will execute logic in `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()` etc. It will take variable amount of time depending upon how time consuming the logic is.
- Before finishing completely, A will do same for logic in `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` etc (or just some of these, depending upon at what point you called `finish()`).